# How to keep process backgrounded after script is done?

Tags: shell, background-process, zsh

I'm trying to background a process in a zsh script:

```
lein servlet run &
```

but after the script is done `jobs` shows:

```
[4]  + 98346 suspended (tty input)  lein servlet run
```

If I run `lein servlet run &` from my command line, it works fine, and doesn't get suspended.

Answer (score 1):

After researching, I learned that `(tty input)` means the process is waiting for terminal input, but it doesn't actually take input from me (someone must've wrote something hacky). To solve the problem, I gave it fake input:

```
lein servlet run </dev/zero &
```

Now it works. :D